# Div inline not working

Tags: html, css

I  want to display the menu in inline form but it's not working .Any help ?(Don't worry about the pictures).[Here is a screenshot of what I want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AXPo0.png).The "As seen " will occupy the red holder on the screenshot.

```html
<div class="header" style="display:inline;">

  <div style="font-size:26px;">
    <span> As seen on</span>
  </div>

  <div>
    <a href="https://www.marketingignite.com/basic-commonsensical-seo-tips-and-tricks/" target="_blank"><img style="vertical-align: middle; background-color:#000;" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/marketing_ignite_logo.png" /></a>
  </div>

  <div>
    <a href="<?php echo esc_url(home_url()); ?>"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/logo.gif" alt="Logo Buyseoleads"></a>
  </div>

  <div class="seenBefore2" style="font-size:26px;">
    <span>As seen on</span>
  </div>

  <div>
    <a href="http://www.releasewire.com/press-releases/explaining-the-advantage-of-verified-and-exclusive-ppc-and-seo-leads-how-buy-seo-leads-helps-agencies-achieve-greater-success-and-conversions-549381.htm" target="_blank"><img style="vertical-align: middle; background-color:#000;" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/release_wire_logo.png"/></a>
    <!--img src="<?php //echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/daily-news-newspaper-headline.jpg" alt="Daily News Newspaper Headline"-->
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Did you tried "inline-block" instead of "inline"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a lot to go on here but I'll give it a try.

Every `<div>` has block context by default. Setting `display: inline;` on a parent `<div>` will not get inherited by child `<div>`s. Apply `display: inline;` to all `<div>`. Use `<span>` instead of `<div>` as it's an inline element by default and won't try to take up the whole width of the parent element by default.

Personally I would change the markup a bit if you're Looking to create a menu. Use `<nav>`, `<ul>`, `<li>`, `<a>` etc. instead. Perhaps something like I have below.

```css
ul,
li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
li {
  padding: 3px 6px;
  float: left;
}
li img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<header>

  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>As seen on
        <a href="#">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50/ffcc00/">
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>As seen on
        <a href="#">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50/cc0000/">
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `display: inline;` won't allow any block styling. And you used it on block element. If you want elements to be on the same line, you should consider using, for example, float property

```
.header div {
  float: left;
}
```

But do not forget about clearing the floats.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want your blocks (as seen on, with image) in a row? If so, you can use floats. Note also I have replaced your images with placeholdit ones.

https://jsfiddle.net/aa8zs200/

```
<div style="width: 100%; position: relative;">

  <div style="float: left; margin-right: 10px;">
    <div style="font-size:26px;"><span> As seen on</span></div>
    <div>
      <a href="https://www.marketingignite.com/basic-commonsensical-seo-tips-and-tricks/" target="_blank">
        <img style="vertical-align: middle; background-color:#000;" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" /> </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div style="float: left; margin-right: 10px;">
    <div style="font-size:26px;"><span> As seen on</span></div>
    <div>
      <a href="<?php echo esc_url(home_url()); ?>"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="Logo Buyseoleads"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
span{
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
```

**or**

```
span{
display:block;
float:left;
padding:0 10px;
}
```

Comment: `<span>`s don't have margin and padding by default. Instead of setting `<span>` to `display: block;` use `<div>` instead.

Answer (score 0):

For this question,You should set the `display:inline` attribute for all of the inner divs, not for the outer div.